# Alternative library in Flutter like Reachability in iOS?

Tags: flutter

Im new in *Flutter Framework* and unable to find any replacement library for internet availability like we have Reachability in iOS. any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following plugin to check connectivity

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/connectivity

```
 import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

  var connectivityResult = await (new 
  Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
  }.  else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) 
{
   // I am connected to a wifi network.
 }
```

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i appreciate your approach too.

Answer (score 5):

You can build *reactive layouts* using a ***[`StreamBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)*** and the ***[`connectivity`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity)*** plugin:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> result) {
    if (result.data == ConnectivityResult.wifi)
      return Text('wifi');
    return Text('no wifi');
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity) plugin. This plugin works for iOS and Android.

Sample usage to check current status:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

    var connectivityResult = await (new Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      // I am connected to a mobile network.
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      // I am connected to a wifi network.
    }
```

Comment: He posted it at the same time though. The code is coming from the plugin readme.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for  the clarifcation